# ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ в классе

Tags: c++

Есть функция внутри класса Buffer
`void setBuffer(unsigned int n, GLuint *buffer, typeBuffers types);`
После она вызывается в классе Game

```
Buffer buf;
buf.setBuffer(1, &VBO, ArrayBuffer);
```

и при компиляции visual studio ругается:

```
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall Buffer::setBuffer(unsigned int,unsigned int *,enum typeBuffers)" (?setBuffer@Buffer@@QAEXIPAIW4typeBuffers@@@Z) в функции "public: virtual bool __thiscall Game::InitializeGame(void)" (?InitializeGame@Game@@UAE_NXZ)  MyEngine    C:\Users\angel\Source\Repos\GLEngine\MyEngine\MyEngine\Game.obj 1
```

Comment: Ну а она определена или только объявлена? По тем огрызкам обрывков выяснить это возможным не представляется.

Comment: можете предоставить больше кода, а то ничего не понятно.

Comment: Да она и определена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что функция была помечена как inline из за чего и возникала ошибка